# gettin the all the column values of datagridview in vb.net in variables on enter key event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

```
Private Sub dgcustomerlist_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dgcustomerlist.KeyPress
    Dim custcode As String
    Dim custname As String
    Dim custmobile As String
    'Dim rows As DataGridViewRow = dgcustomerlist.SelectedRows(0)


    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        custcode = dgcustomerlist.SelectedCells(0).Value
        custname = dgcustomerlist.SelectedCells(1).Value
        custmobile = dgcustomerlist.SelectedCells(2).Value
        MsgBox("the selected value is", custcode)
    End If
```

heres the above code,the situation is that i want the column value of the selected row in gridview in the particular variables.but i am getting error in custname as it throws index out of range.kindly tell help me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You have to provide more information regarding your input conditions and what you want to accomplish: why are you considering three different selected cells? Did you mean perhaps 3 different columns?

Comment: @varocarbas sorry my mistake,yes you are right i meant 3 different columns on the same row for which i want that values to be captured in the respective variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears because CustName cell is not selected when the code is running (maybe because pressing ENTER deselect it).

You can set `DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect` or you can use `.CurrentRow.Cells` instead of `.SelectedCells`; for example:

```
custcode = dgcustomerlist.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
custname = dgcustomerlist.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
custmobile = dgcustomerlist.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
```

Comment: thanks for your solution it worked.my actual need is that this datagridview  is called from another form on the enter key event.after this form is loaded i want the selected values to be passed back to the calling forms datagridview.can you guide me

Comment: This is another question. Open a new question and someone (maybe me) will gave you an answer.

Comment: If the OP is happy with your solution, excellent. But the solution you propose does not relate too well with what might be really happening. The line  custname = dgcustomerlist.SelectedCells(1).Value is fine, although the OP might be using it wrongly (it refers to the second selected cell). The code you proposed does not mention the selected cells at all (implicit in the OP's code). If the OP was getting an error was because there weren't 3 cells being selected; the solution for this problem is not writing a code accounting for different cells.

Comment: The title of this question is clearer than the question itself. I thought the only problem is that he uses the wrong property.